# Doubt on a ("straightfoward") derivation of Weyl tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

**I) My doubt:**

After Kruskal coordinates, we can introduce penrose diagrams after a quick talk about conformal metric tensors. Then, after the study of penrose diagrams the student should know that a conformal transformation on the metric is :

$$\tilde{g}_{ik} = e^{2\phi(x^{j})}g_{ik}. \tag{1}$$

Now, Weyl tensor is somewhat a advanced topic. But if you use metric $(1)$ to rewrite Christoffel Symbols, then you can automatically write the Riemman as a some sort of "Conformal Riemann tensor":

$$\tilde{R}_{ijkl} = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{  \frac{\partial^{2}\tilde{g}_{il}}{\partial x^{k}\partial x^{j}} + \frac{\partial^{2}\tilde{g}_{jk}}{\partial x^{l}\partial x^{i}} - \frac{\partial^{2}\tilde{g}_{jl}}{\partial x^{k}\partial x^{i}} - \frac{\partial^{2}\tilde{g}_{ik}}{\partial x^{l}\partial x^{j}}                  \Bigg\} + \tilde{g}_{mn}(\tilde{\Gamma ^{m}_{jk}}\tilde{\Gamma ^{n}_{il}}-\tilde{\Gamma ^{m}_{jl}}\tilde{\Gamma ^{n}_{ik}}) = e^{2\phi}\Bigg[ R_{ijkl} + (g_{il}\phi_{jk} + g_{jk}\phi_{il}-g_{ik}\phi_{jl}-g_{jl}\phi_{ik}) + (g_{il}g_{jk}-g_{ik}g_{jl})(g^{mn}\phi,_{m}\phi,_{n}) \Bigg] \tag{2}$$

Where $\phi_{ab} =: \frac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial x^{a} \partial x^{b}} - \frac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial x^{b} \partial x^{a}}$ and $\phi,_{a} =: \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^{a}}$.

After some straightfoward (but not easy) calculations, which are $\tilde{g}^{ik}\tilde{R}_{ijkl}$ and $\tilde{g}^{jl}\tilde{R}_{jl}$ (to construct Ricci and Ricci Scalar), we realize that when we perform these calculations and we use $(1)$ we reach on:

$$ \phi_{jl} = -\frac{1}{2}(\tilde{R}_{jl} - R_{jl}) + \frac{1}{12}(\tilde{R}\tilde{g}_{jl} - Rg_{jl})-\frac{1}{2}g_{jl}g^{mn}\phi,_{m}\phi,_{n}.              \tag{3}$$

If we raise the index $i$ of $(2)$ we obtain:

$$\tilde{R}^{p}_{jkl} = R^{p}_{jkl} + \delta^{p}_{l}\phi_{jk} - \delta^{p}_{k}\phi_{jl} + g^{ip}(g_{jk}\phi_{il} - g_{jl}\phi_{ik} ) + (\delta^{p}_{l}g_{jk} - \delta^{p}_{k}g_{jl})(g^{mn}\phi,_{m}\phi,_{n}). \tag{4}$$

Then using $(3)$ in $(4)$ we finally state a "conformal invariance":

$$\tilde{R}^{p}_{jkl} - \frac{1}{2}(\delta^{p}_{k}\tilde{R}_{jl} + \tilde{g}_{jl}\tilde{R}^{p}_{k} - \delta^{p}_{k}\tilde{R}_{jk} - \tilde{g}_{jk}\tilde{R}^{p}_{l} ) - \frac{\tilde{R}}{6}(\delta^{p}_{l}\tilde{g}_{jk} - \delta^{p}_{k}\tilde{g}_{jl}) =$$  $$=R^{p}_{jkl} - \frac{1}{2}(\delta^{p}_{k}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R^{p}_{k} - \delta^{p}_{k}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R^{p}_{l} ) - \frac{R}{6}(\delta^{p}_{l}g_{jk} - \delta^{p}_{k}g_{jl}).\tag{5}$$

It's quite clear that we can simply rename the tensors in $(5)$ as:

$$\tilde{C}^{p}_{jkl} = C^{p}_{jkl}. \tag{6}$$

Then, due to conformal invariance, we can establish:

$$C^{p}_{jkl} = R^{p}_{jkl} - \frac{1}{2}(\delta^{p}_{k}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R^{p}_{k} - \delta^{p}_{k}R_{jl} - g_{jk}R^{p}_{l} ) - \frac{R}{6}(\delta^{p}_{l}g_{jk} - \delta^{p}_{k}g_{jl}).\tag{7}$$

Finally, if we move down the $p$ index we recover the well-known *Weyl Tensor*:

$$g_{ip}C^{p}_{jkl}  \implies $$

$$C_{ijkl} = R_{ijkl} - \frac{1}{2}(g_{ik}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R_{ik} - g_{il}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R_{il} ) - \frac{R}{6}(g_{il}g_{jk} - g_{ik}g_{jl}).\tag{8}$$

> My doubt is: can we actually call this an derivation of  the Weyl tensor for $n=4$?

**II) Motivation for this question:**

If $(6)$ can lead to a "derivation" of Weyl tensor we can explore further interresting conclusions like decompositon of Riemann Tensor and general form of Weyl Tensor (for higher dimensions):

$$R_{ijkl} = C_{ijkl} + \frac{1}{2}(g_{ik}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R_{ik} - g_{il}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R_{il} ) + \frac{R}{6}(g_{il}g_{jk} - g_{ik}g_{jl})  =: C_{ijkl} + E_{ijkl} + G_{ijkl} \tag{9}$$

$$R_{ijkl} = C_{ijkl} + \frac{1}{n-2}(g_{ik}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R_{ik} - g_{il}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R_{il} ) + \frac{R}{(n-1)(n-2)}(g_{il}g_{jk} - g_{ik}g_{jl})\tag{10} $$

Textbooks prefer to work differently, like imposing an *ansatz* about Riemann:

$$R_{ijkl} = C_{ijkl} + P(g_{ik}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R_{ik} - g_{il}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R_{il} ) + Q(g_{il}g_{jk} - g_{ik}g_{jl})R,  \tag{11}$$

then workout to figure out $P$ and $Q$.

Or like this gentleman: http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~vincent/4500.6-001/Cosmology/WeylTensor.htm

Comment: What is the actual question? But anyways, for 2-index tensors, you can decompose them into irreducible parts - into symmetric and antisymmetric parts, and the symmetric part further into a trace and a tracefree part. The "ansatz" is basically the equivalent decomposition for "Bianchi-tensors", tensors with the same symmetries as the curvature tensor. Check out John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds for a well-motivated derivation of the Weyl tensor.

Comment: But What I have done to derive weyl tensor is wrong?

Comment: @BenceRacskó So, I read the chapter about the Weyl Tensor on Lee's book; it's pretty good actually, and I found a motivation to study the famous Kulkarni-Nomizu product. But I really need to protest against the "well-motivated derivation", because there's a lot of math and then Lee simply define de Weyl tensor. What I wrote in this question you do not need to define nothing, you simply calculate with a conformal metric, then you obtain Weyl tensor directly for $n=4$.

Comment: It's well motivated, because it arises from the question that how much info about the curvature tensor is contained in the Ricci tensor - which is relevant to physics because the Einstein field equation fixes directly only the Ricci tensor. But deriving the Weyl tensor from conformal invariance is perfectly valid and well-motivated as well and frankly, I still don't understand what is the principal question in the OP.

Comment: Also if you are wondering if the conformal invariance thing works in any dimensions as well - Lee's book also talks about it. In $n>3$, the Weyl-tensor is conformally invariant and the metric is locally conformally flat iff the Weyl-tensor vanishes, in $n=3$ the Weyl tensor vanishes identically but the Cotton tensor takes its place as a measure of conformal flatness, and for $n=2$, the metric is conformally flat by default.